# Unity: https post and get requests using JSONObj

Tags: c#, android, json, https, unity-game-engine

i'm. i'm making a 2d game for android device in unity and i'm having difficulties to understand the all WWW and http Forms thing.

what i basically need to do is post request to https url and get access token using credentials(username and password) and i must use JSON object.

in more detailed way i need to :

1.create 2 requests to the server to acquire additional assets: In order to receive an Access Token, i need to create an HTTP POST request to specific url containing JSON object with two elements - 'username' and 'password' .

2.create an HTTP GET request to specific url 'auth' header and use the Access Token acquired in the first request. The response contains a JSON object with 5 URLs of the Additional Art Assets.

3.then i need to put those 5 urls containing images randomly in my game.

i know how to add prefabs to the game i just couldn't find one understandable guide to go thru this proccess. i downloaded JSON object from the asset store

no need to write a code even tho it will more clear to understand ,i just need guides on how to get to the result.

Thanks a lot i appreciate every single Help!

Answer (score 0):

**(Deprecated):** [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) and [WWWForm](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html) should be enough to do all you want.

**(Updated version):**
I'll update my answer as @LabGecko suggested.

To send web requests to server you should use [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html). This is how I send Post requests (pass some function that accept string as a parameter for `callback` to handle result).

```
//callback is used to handle server response
private IEnumerator SendPostRequest(string url, List<IMultipartFormSection> data, 
Action<string> callback, string _token = null)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, data))
    {
        //Set auth token if available
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_token))
            www.SetRequestHeader("authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", _token));

        www.SendWebRequest();

        while (!www.isDone)
        {
            yield return false;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }

        if (www.isDone)
        {
            callback(www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Get request looks like this:

```
private IEnumerator SendGetRequest(string url, Action<string> callback, string _token = null)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_token))
            www.SetRequestHeader("authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", _token));

        www.SendWebRequest();

        while (!www.isDone)
        {
            yield return false;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }

        if (www.isDone)
        {
            callback(www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

After response is received you can handle it's JSON part with [JSONUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html).

Comment: This link is broken and parts of this answer are deprecated. Is there a way to make this question no longer appear in search results? It still lists high when searching on URL and JSON.